# QGraphicsItem: Why no `stackAfter` method?

Tags: qt, pyqt4, pyside

I'm having an annoying time trying to get around the 'recommended' way of doing something.

So, I have a stack of cards. I want to make it so that when I deal a card, it becomes the last-drawn object of the entire scene (typical `bring_to_front` functionality).

The recommended way to do this is just adding to the object's `zValue` until it is larger than all the rest, but I was hoping to do away with rather "lazy" integers running around all over the place with judicious use of the `stackBefore` method, which simulates reorganizing the order in which objects were added to the scene.

This works perfectly fine when I shuffle my cards in a limited set (get list of selected items, random.shuffle, for item do item.stackBefore(next item)), but it is certainly not working when it comes to bubbling the card to the top of the entire scene.

I considered adding a copy of the object to the scene and then removing the original, but it just seems like I should be able to do `stackAfter` like I would when using a Python list (or `insertAt` or something).

Sample code:

```
  def deal_items(self):
    if not self.selection_is_stack():
      self.statusBar().showMessage("You must deal from a stack")
      return

    item_list = self.scene.sorted_selection()
    for i,item in enumerate(item_list[::-1]):
      width = item.boundingRect().width()
      item.moveBy(width+i*width*0.6,0)

      another_list = self.scene.items()[::-1]
      idx = another_list.index(item)
      for another_item in another_list[idx+1:]:
        another_item.stackBefore(item)
```

This works. It just seems somewhat... ugly.

Comment: maybe there's a trick like `setZValue=0` automatically places the object at the end of all objects with zValue==0? i don't know

Answer (score 1):

`self.scene.items` returns the items in the stacking order ([link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html#items)).  So if you want to `stackAfter` an item, you can just query the z value of the current topmost item and then set the z value of the new topmost card to a value one larger.

`item.setZValue(self.scene.items().first().zValue() + 1)`

Hope that helps.

Edit added src for `stackBefore` and `setZValue` from http://gitorious.org/qt/
`src/gui/graphicsview/qgraphicsitem.cpp`

```
void QGraphicsItem::stackBefore(const QGraphicsItem *sibling)
{
    if (sibling == this)
        return;
    if (!sibling || d_ptr->parent != sibling->parentItem()) {
        qWarning("QGraphicsItem::stackUnder: cannot stack under %p, which must be a sibling", sibling);
        return;
    }
    QList<QGraphicsItem *> *siblings = d_ptr->parent
                                       ? &d_ptr->parent->d_ptr->children
                                       : (d_ptr->scene ? &d_ptr->scene->d_func()->topLevelItems : 0);
    if (!siblings) {
        qWarning("QGraphicsItem::stackUnder: cannot stack under %p, which must be a sibling", sibling);
        return;
    }

    // First, make sure that the sibling indexes have no holes. This also
    // marks the children list for sorting.
    if (d_ptr->parent)
        d_ptr->parent->d_ptr->ensureSequentialSiblingIndex();
    else
        d_ptr->scene->d_func()->ensureSequentialTopLevelSiblingIndexes();

    // Only move items with the same Z value, and that need moving.
    int siblingIndex = sibling->d_ptr->siblingIndex;
    int myIndex = d_ptr->siblingIndex;
    if (myIndex >= siblingIndex) {
        siblings->move(myIndex, siblingIndex);
        // Fixup the insertion ordering.
        for (int i = 0; i < siblings->size(); ++i) {
            int &index = siblings->at(i)->d_ptr->siblingIndex;
            if (i != siblingIndex && index >= siblingIndex && index <= myIndex)
                ++index;
        }
        d_ptr->siblingIndex = siblingIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i < siblings->size(); ++i) {
            int &index = siblings->at(i)->d_ptr->siblingIndex;
            if (i != siblingIndex && index >= siblingIndex && index <= myIndex)
                siblings->at(i)->d_ptr->siblingOrderChange();
        }
        d_ptr->siblingOrderChange();
    }
}

void QGraphicsItem::setZValue(qreal z)
{
    const QVariant newZVariant(itemChange(ItemZValueChange, z));
    qreal newZ = newZVariant.toReal();
    if (newZ == d_ptr->z)
        return;

    if (d_ptr->scene && d_ptr->scene->d_func()->indexMethod != QGraphicsScene::NoIndex) {
        // Z Value has changed, we have to notify the index.
        d_ptr->scene->d_func()->index->itemChange(this, ItemZValueChange, &newZ);
    }

    d_ptr->z = newZ;
    if (d_ptr->parent)
        d_ptr->parent->d_ptr->needSortChildren = 1;
    else if (d_ptr->scene)
        d_ptr->scene->d_func()->needSortTopLevelItems = 1;

    if (d_ptr->scene)
        d_ptr->scene->d_func()->markDirty(this, QRectF(), /*invalidateChildren=*/true);

    itemChange(ItemZValueHasChanged, newZVariant);

    if (d_ptr->flags & ItemNegativeZStacksBehindParent)
        setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemStacksBehindParent, z < qreal(0.0));

    if (d_ptr->isObject)
        emit static_cast<QGraphicsObject *>(this)->zChanged();
}
```

Comment: it does (and I like the `first` call, hadn't seen it before), but I just want to use zValues for a different thing altogether. I thought about making the dz = 0.000001 so I never have to worry about breaching barriers, but then I have to track it and keep resetting the values every once in a while... idk, I just feel like squeezing as much value out of stackBefore as possible.

Comment: If you need another a "z" variable, you could subclass the item and add it.  If you read the doc for stack before, all it is doing is editing the z value based on another object's z value. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#stackBefore Good luck.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#sorting also talks about using parenting to group and sort items (`ItemStacksBehindParent`).

Comment: hey @phyatt, in your link it says

"The sibling must have the same Z value as this item, otherwise calling this function will have no effect."
"When the Z values are the same, the insertion order will decide the stacking order."

That's what I'm trying to use/modify, the insertion order. It seems more robust and perfectly suited for my purposes.

Comment: I see your point... but the documentation doesn't point towards any easy way to do it.  You could look at how stackBefore is implemented in the source, and create a similar one that way...

Comment: I know. I'll keep my hack-ish method then, though it seems like it may get cost-intensive.